# Class methods not made public

Tags: objective-c

I've got two classes, `Workout` and `Action`. `Workout` has a method called `associateActionsAndCounts`, which takes stored `NSString` data and `NSInteger` data and creates an `Action` for them. Now, the `Action` class has factory methods that I've written to make this method simpler, however when I try and call one of the factory methods, Xcode tells me "No known class method for selector 'initWithName:andCount`".

Action.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Action : NSObject
+(Action *)initWithName:(NSString*)name;
+(Action *)initWithName:(NSString*)name andCount:(NSInteger*)count;
+(Action *)initWithName:(NSString*)name andCount:(NSInteger*)count andImage:(UIImage*)image;
@property UIImage *image;
@property NSString *name;
@property NSInteger *count;
@end
```

Action.m

```
#import "Action.h"
@implementation Action
@synthesize image;
@synthesize name;
@synthesize count;
#pragma mark - factory methods
+(Action *)initWithName:(NSString *)name {
    Action *newAct = [Action alloc];
    [newAct setName:name];
    return newAct;
}
+(Action *)initWithName:(NSString*)name andCount:(NSInteger*)count {
    Action *newAct = [Action alloc];
    [newAct setName:name];
    [newAct setCount:count];
    return  newAct;
}
+(Action *)initWithName:(NSString *)name andCount:(NSInteger *)count andImage:(UIImage *)image {
    Action *newAct = [Action alloc];
    [newAct setName:name];
    [newAct setCount:count];
    [newAct setImage:image];
    return newAct;
}
@end
```

Workout.m - `associateActionsAndCounts` (actions and counts are ivars)

```
-(void)associateActionsAndCounts {
    for (int i=0;i<actions.count;i++) {
        NSString *name = [actions objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *num = [counts objectAtIndex:i];
        Action *newAction  = [Action initWithName:name andCount:num]; //no known class method for selector
        [actionsData addObject:newAction];
    }
}
```

---

Edit:

With [Michael Dautermann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/981049/michael-dautermann)'s suggestions, my code looks like this now:

```
-(void)associateActionsAndCounts {
    for (int i=0;i<actions.count;i++) {
        NSString *actionName = [actions objectAtIndex:i];
        NSInteger num = [[NSString stringWithString:[counts objectAtIndex:i]] intValue];
        Action *newAction  = [Action actionWithName:actionName andCount:num];
        [actionsData addObject:newAction];
    }
}
```

Action.h

```
+(Action *)actionWithName:(NSString*)name;
+(Action *)actionWithName:(NSString*)name andCount:(NSInteger*)count;
+(Action *)actionWithName:(NSString*)name andCount:(NSInteger*)count andImage:(UIImage*)image;
```

But i'm still getting the same error.

> No known Class method for selector "actionWithName:andCount"

Comment: I guess you did import `Action.h`? And you should probably replace `NSInteger *` in your class with `NSInteger`. Right now you are using pointers to NSInteger, that's probably not what you want.

Comment: yep, in both `Workout.h` and `Workout.m` (even though that's not required)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few problems here.

Number one, the "`num`" parameter you're passing into "`andCount`" in your code is a `NSString` object and not the `NSInteger` object that the method you've declared is expecting.

Number two, if you're doing this kind of "factory" method, don't name it "`initWithName: andCount:`" because that implies you're expecting an "`alloc`" method before the "`init`".  Declare it with a different name, like "`+(Action *) actionWithName: andCount:`".  Otherwise, you (or worse, *another programmer who is not you*) will be mightily confused when looking at this code if there are memory issues down the road.

Comment: right. Thanks for the suggestions, do you have any idea why I can't call my factory methods?

Comment: if you change "`num`" to a NSInteger you will be able to call your factory methods.

Comment: I have, still getting the same error, "No known class method for selector 'actionWithName:andCount'"

Comment: Change your declaration to "`+(Action *)actionWithName:(NSString*)name andCount:(NSInteger)count;`" (i.e. use "`NSInteger`" and not a "`NSInteger *`" pointer) and see if you have better luck.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow `Workout.h` and `Workout.m` weren't in the project folder, but rather in another project folder. So `Action.h` wasn't included.